# Find the longest common prefix from a list

Tags: c

There are other answers online for this problem. However, I need some help to identify what is incorrect with the code that I've written.

**Question:** Write a function to find the longest common prefix string amongst an array of strings. If there is no common prefix, return an empty string "".

```
Example 1:
Input: strs = ["flower","flow","flight"]
Output: "fl"

Example 2:
Input: strs = ["dog","racecar","car"]
Output: ""
Explanation: There is no common prefix among the input strings.
```

The following C code is a solution that I came up with for this problem, but it doesn't work in certain cases. I'd appreciate it if someone would show me what is wrong with this code.

The code below passes some of the tests thrown at it. (i.e. `["flower","flow","flight"]`)

However, other cases like `["ab", "a"]` would result in the program throwing a heap-buffer-overflow error.

```
char * longestCommonPrefix(char ** strs, int strsSize){
    if(strlen(strs[0]) == 0) return "";
    if(strsSize == 1) return strs[0];
    
    char* finale = calloc(strlen(*strs), sizeof(char));
    strcpy(finale, "");
    
    int ptr = 0;
    char* thechar = strs[0][ptr];
    int tocontinue = 1;
    while(thechar != '\0') {
        for (int i = 1; i < strsSize; i++) {
            if (strs[i][ptr] == '\0' || strs[i][ptr] != thechar) {
                tocontinue = 0;
            }
        }
        if (!tocontinue) {
            break;
        }
        finale[strlen(finale)] = thechar;
        finale[strlen(finale) + 1] = '\0';
        ptr++;
        thechar = strs[0][ptr];
    }
        
    finale = realloc(finale, sizeof(finale));
    return

 finale;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to debug it youself? Run you program in a debugger and trace it as it runs. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). If you have already done so then what did you find? Where does it start to go wrong?

Comment: `finale = realloc(finale, sizeof(finale));` that doesn't do what you probably think it does. `sizeof(finale)` is effectively `sizeof(char *)`. Needs to be `strlen(finale)+1` instead.

Comment: My apologies. I've actually tried running this in gdb but I'm still a bit new to how it works so it didn't prove to be that helpful. I'll try looking into that.

Comment: `char* finale = calloc(strlen(*strs), sizeof(char));` That buffer is not big enough if the longest prefix is the whole word. Need one extra byte for the NUL terminator.

Comment: Tnis isn't right: `char* thechar = strs[0][ptr];` `strs[0][ptr]` is a `char`, not `char*`.

Comment: `calloc()` fills the memory with zero bytes, so you don't need to do `strcpy(finale, "");`

Comment: Appreciate the tips. I've fixed all the errors mentioned above. The same problem is still presisting, however. Could there be an error with the `strs[i][ptr]` reading past the null terminator from a string because that string doesn't have a `ptr`th char?

Comment: You do not actually need to allocate or copy any strings, except possibly the final result at tye very end, to solve this problem. Certainly you don't need any realloc.

Comment: An easy solution https://youtu.be/f-JiELCbkOs